# How do I copy (DOS) files from location A to B in DOS that don't already exist in C?

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have a lot of files that are getting produced by an extract tool and dumped to a folder on a server. This folder is often getting files added to it as the extract process runs regularly.

Once the files are produced, they are copied to another server where they are processed. Once processed, they have either ".loaded" or ".error" appended to the filename (depending on whether processing was successful or not) and are then moved to another folder. So something like:

```
ServerA:
\source

ServerB:
\unprocessed 
\processed
```

So \source is where the extract process dumps the files; \unprocessed is where the files are coped to and read from for processing, and \processed is where the files are moved to once they've been processed.

What I need to do is create a batch file that will copy from \ServerA\source to \ServerB\unprocessed all files that don't already exist in \Server B\processed. The slight extra complication is that the filenames in \processed will have ".loaded" or ".error" appended to their filenames. (So fileA.abc becomes fileA.abc.loaded if successfully processed or fileA.abc.error if not).

So when the process is run, it would need to, for each file in \ServerA\source, check whether that file exists in \ServerB\processed (with either a ".loaded" or ".error" extension); if it doesn't then copy it to \ServerB\unprocessed, otherwise ignore it.

Is it possible to do this in DOS? Or would some other method be better? VBScript maybe?

Comment: Is it really DOS (command.com) or it is windows (cmd.exe)?

Comment: I guess it would be cmd.exe. Sorry...I tend to class them as the same thing, though I appreciate they are different

Answer (score 0):

You could use a batch file:

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b ServerA\source\') do copy %%f ServerB\processed\%%f if not exist ServerB\processed\%%f if not exist ServerB\processed\%%f.loaded if not exist ServerB\processed\%%f.error
```

The "for" loops iterates over the files in origin directory. For each file it checks if exists another file with same name in destination, if not then copies it.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Isn't it rather "if .... command" instead of "command if ..."? (btw: DOS doesn't support `for /f`; cmd does)

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%f in ("\\serverA\source\*") do (
  echo processing %%f
  if not exist "\\serverB\processed\%%~nxf.* (
    echo ... copying %%~nxf...
    copy "%%f" "\\serverB\unprocessed\%%~nxf"
  )
)
```

for every file in "source" do:

if there is no file with the same name plus any extension in "processed",

copy the file to "unprocessed".

`%%~nxf` gives you (n)ame and e(x)tension of the file (%%f)